# Get all tables where there is no booking on this time or date

Tags: sql

So basically I have a tables table. And a bookings table. A table can be assigned to a booking via the `table_no` column. The booking also has a `reservation_time` and `reservation_date` columns. What I'd like my query to do, is to return all tables that aren't linked to a booking on a certain time or date. It's really bugging me.

Here is what my query looks like as of now

```
select t.id, t.number
FROM tables t JOIN 
     bookings b
     ON b.table_no = t.number JOIN
     reservation_time_data r
     ON r.id = b.reservation_time
WHERE t.number != b.table_no AND b.reservation_date != '2020-07-22' AND 45 NOT BETWEEN r.start_time AND r.end_time
```

Comment: What does on a certain "time or date" mean?  I understand one or both but not "or".  Also tag with the database you are using.   And your question mentions two tables, but your query has three.  And why is an integer `45` being compared to columns called "time"?

Comment: I should say time and date. I want to to create a dropdown of tables after entering a time and date. But if a table is occupied on that time and date then I dont want it to show

Comment: You're using a join condition that says one then and then filtering on the exact opposite later. This obviously can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `not exists`.  Based on your sample query, I think this is:

```
select t.id, t.number 
from tables t 
where not exists (select 1
                  from bookings b join
                       reservation_time_data r 
                       on r.id = b.reservation_time 
                  where b.table_no = t.number and
                        b.reservation_date = '2020-07-22' and
                        45 >= r.start_time and
                        45 <= r.end_time
                 );
```

Comment: Yes I think this is heading in the right direction, will do some testing with this. Thanks!

Comment: Ive tested it and it returns me the tables inluding the one i dont want, i tried just filtering by date too and that doesnt work

Comment: @TiernO . . . It should only return `t.number` that have no record during the specified timeslot.  Can you set up a db<>fiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it with left join like this

```
    select t.id, t.number FROM tables t Left JOIN bookings b ON b.table_no = t.number 
 WHERE  b.table_no is null AND (b.reservation_date = '2020-07-22' Or b.[your time column here] BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.end_time )
```

Comment: r is not defined?

Comment: I copied the where clause from your own query, change r to your table alias that i think it would be b.

Comment: I get returned 0 rows. In the database, only 1 has a table assigned to it

Comment: test this one without any date filter: select t.id, t.number FROM tables t Left JOIN bookings b ON b.table_no = t.number 
 WHERE  b.table_no is null

Comment: There's no point in using a left join and then filtering on the inner table afterward. If you do need the extra conditions then move then into the join condition.